# Building Vector for a sentence in doc2vec from an untrained data set

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I have a `doc2vec` model build from my data, now I have a new sentence in run time which does not belong to the trained data set.

How can I build or predict a vector for this sentence from my model?

How should I handle unknown words in this sentence?

Answer (score 4):

Gensim (development version) seems to have a method to infer vectors of new sentences. Check out `model.infer_vector(NewDocument)` method in https://github.com/gojomo/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/doc2vec.py

Comment: It will not affect my model..I used it but sometime it returned different vector for same sentence.

Comment: `infer_vector()` is available in the last few official releases of gensim. Also, the doc2vec algorithm involves some randomness. If you're using negative-sampling, a different set of negative-examples can be tried each call/iteration. From the 'window' parameter, the algorithm (inherited from word2vec) chooses some random smaller window up-to your chosen value. So without taking extra steps, repeated inferences (like repeated training runs) will give similar but not identical results. If you need perfect reproducibility, see some discussion at https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/447